# she/he didn't/doesn't/hasn't/haven't sent it as yet

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I have seen these sentences:

> she/he didn't send it as yet.

> she/he doesn't send it as yet.

> she/he hasn't sent it as yet.

> she/he haven't sent it as yet.

Which is correct? Please explain elaborately with grammar.

Comment: Which is correct?

Comment: I, as a British English speaker, would say "She hasn't sent it yet". An American might say "She didn't send it yet". _Doesn't_ is not appropriate when referring to an action, although we could say "He doesn't know about it yet".

Comment: In some writings, I have seen to write that he doesn't send it yet. But, it's not grammatically wrong, if anyone uses it.

Comment: It may not be grammatically wrong, but it isn't idiomatic.

Comment: It is not American English to use *did* with *yet*. It is basically English speakers, including Brits, who don't know or care about grammar. As an American English speaker, I would also use has/have with yet. And not the simple past.

Comment: Leema, you have to show an effort here. We really don't do homework for people here. You could paste each of those sentences in Word and then look up verb tenses.